# Django formwizard: passing data between forms

Tags: python, django

I have a form wizard that contains 3 forms. Basically, what I am trying to do is to pass data from first and second forms to the third one. What I tried is to add a dictionary attribute to wizard class and update that dictionary every time the method `process_step` is called. [Django 1.4 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.process_step) says that this method is called every time a page is rendered for all submitted steps.

In the following sample code, dictionary attribute is changed with integer `self.test` to keep it simple. In this case, every time the method `process_step` is called, the value of `self.test` is 2, never increases. It seems that the method `__init__` is called for each form.

```
class MyWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyWizard, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.test = 1

    def process_step(self, form):
        self.test += 1  
        print self.test
        return self.get_form_step_data(form)
```

Other than this solution, is there a more elegant way to pass data between forms of form wizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with sessions passing the "inital" info to the 3rd form. 
Here's an example of [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029942/need-clarification-on-using-django-1-4-form-wizards-specifically-pre-filling-an/11135623#11135623).

Answer (score 8):

What I would do is the following:

```
class MyWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyWizard, self).get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)
        if self.steps.step1 == 3:
            data_from_step_1 = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0') # zero indexed
            data_from_step_2 = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('1') # zero indexed
            context.update({'data_from_step_1':data_from_step_1,
                            'data_from_step_2':data_from_step_2})
        return context
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, spent all day trying to get this working.

Answer (score 2):

I have little experience with formwizard but from django docs [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_context_data) looks like what you're after.

```
def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyWizard, self).get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)
    if self.steps.current == 'my_step_name':
        context.update({'another_var': True})
    return context
```